# Created CustomUserDetailService. Now what?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am just learning Spring Security. My goal is to authenticate the user by their username and password, which are stored in PostgreSQL.

So far, this is what I have:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class configurator {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                                auth
                                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        )
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

You may also find this code on https://github.com/RezaS/Login-with-Spring-Security.

My question is, what do I do with `CustomUserDetailService` now? Should it be implemented in `Configurator` class? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Can you please take a loot at this example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database .. It's same Database backed auth using userdetailsService... You need to register the bean in context.

Comment: @MaheshBiradar thank you! So if I am not mistaken, I just need to add `@Service` to the class `CustomUserDetailService`.

Comment: Yes,that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomUserDetailService must be annotate @Service or @Component for register  to spring bean context.

Also you can read more about UserDetailsService: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-security/inmemory-jdbc-userdetails-service/

Comment: Yes, probably I was just missing `@Service`. Thank you!